# Php html selected field issue

Tags: php, html

following is my part of html form. If the form is showing a error then i want to select the user selected field. But unfortunately it's not working for me. can you guys help me plz?

**My html form:**

```
<select class="td" name="class_name">
    <option value="">--Select class--</option>
    <?php
    $class = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM e_class");

    while($res =  mysql_fetch_array($class))
    {           
        $class_name_ed = $res['class_name'];
        $class_id_ed = $res['class_id'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo "$class_name_ed"; ?>" <?php 
if(isset($_POST['class_name']) == "$class_name_ed") echo 'selected = "selected"';  ?>> 
<?php echo $class_name_ed; ?></option>";
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

But if i look at the source file then i can see following..
It's selected all the field

```
<select class="td" name="class_name">
    <option value="">--Select class--</option>
    <option value="Three" selected = "selected"> Three</option>";
    <option value="Four" selected = "selected"> Four</option>";
    <option value="Five" selected = "selected"> Five</option>";
</select>
```

**Update:** 
If the option is look like then what can i do:

```
<option value="<?php echo "$class_name_ed | $class_id_ed"; ?>" <?php if 
(isset($_POST['class_name']) && ($_POST['class_name'] == $class_name_ed)) echo 
'selected = "selected"';  ?>> <?php echo $class_name_ed; ?></option>
```

Comment: how does your DB structure look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['class_name']) == "$class_name_ed")
   ^^^^^^
```

you're comparing a boolean true/false value against a string. Most likely you want something more like:

```
if (isset($_POST['class_name']) && ($_POST['class_name'] == $class_name_ed)) {
```

instead.

Comment: And also change `<?php echo $class_name_ed; ?></option>";` to `<?php echo $class_name_ed; ?></option>`

Comment: Ok, @Marc B I'm checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['class_name']) && $_POST['class_name'] == $class_name_ed) echo 'selected';
```

You have an error in the conditional. isset() returns true or false. Also you do not need to wrapp the variable $class_name_ed with "". If you want to be sure that is a string you can cast it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['class_name']) && $_POST['class_name'] == (string)$class_name_ed) echo 'selected';
```

You do not need to use selected="selected" you can mark the option as selected.
 Three